# Thread is not opening the target function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv

I want to open a function which shows the Loading VIDEO on the screen by cv2.imshow() method called.
First  I want to demostrat the code and then the problem.

```
import cv2
import threading


def Load():

    video = cv2.VideoCapture('Loading.mov')

    if video.isOpened() == True:

        cv2.namedWindow("The Video")
        cv2.moveWindow("The Video", 500,200)

    elif video.isOpened() == False:

        print('No Data For Loading Video')
        return 0

    while video.isOpened():

        _, frame = video.read()

        if _ == True:


            cv2.imshow("The Video",frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff == 27:
                break

        if _ == False :

            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()


t = threading.Thread(target = Load)
t.start()
```

*Now, Problem :*

When I call the t.start() **FOR THE FIRST TIME** the thread gets started and shows the video properly.
After the loop breaks, if I try again to make a new `t` as a thread and .start() it again, it doesn't show anything at all ! Not errors, nothing !

> I am using spyder to re run the codes.
>   And I want to re run the video whenever I needed .

Now, Where is the problem ?

Comment: Why are you naming a variable `_` when you're clearly using it? What's going on with the `if ... == True:` and `if ... == False:`? That's doubly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with an mp4-Video (http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) and it works. I converted said video to mov with https://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mov and it still works...

Although I may have an educated guess:
you should try to do every call with a fresh instance of cv2.

I assume the problem could be, that the second call of the thread inherits the state of the first call (especially the internal state of cv2), since it's only a function an therefor the video is in state "already played" or something and doesn't show anything more.

so if you put everything in a class and call with a new instance of cv2 everytime Load() is called, it might work.

```
import cv2
import threading

class Video:
    def play(self):
        video = cv2.VideoCapture('small.mov')

        if video.isOpened() == True:
            cv2.namedWindow("The Video")
            cv2.moveWindow("The Video", 500,200)

        elif video.isOpened() == False:
            print('No Data For Loading Video')
            return 0

        while video.isOpened():
            _, frame = video.read()

            if _ == True:
                cv2.imshow("The Video",frame)

                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff == 27:
                    break

            if _ == False :
                break

        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        video.release()

def Load():
    v=Video()
    v.play()
    del v


t = threading.Thread(target = Load)
t.start()
```